# How do I cancel third party task?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I a have a third party task running in the following code:

```
var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var ct = ts.Token;

var node = Task<IResponseAdapter>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    return NewRequest(n.RequestClass, n.MinCommission, n.MaxCommission).Submit();

}, ct);
```

As you can see, the method call is the only thing inside the task and the whole reason for being inside a task is so that I can cancel it if it times out. A number of third party methods are run sequentially, so it's important to monitor misbehaving/non-responsive jobs and terminate them so that the next job then run.

Elsewhere in my code I have

```
var completed = task.Wait(timeoutValue);

if(!completed) tokensource.Cancel();
```

However, I believe this doesn't actually cancel the task, and only provides a method for accessing it.

So how can I stop the third party webservice method from running?

Comment: [*How do I cancel non-cancelable async operations?*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx) should answer your question. (Spoiler: you can't.)

Comment: Are there any other ways of dealing with this, such as thread join and abort?

Comment: Thread join doesn't cancel anything. Thread abort is very dangerous and really shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly cannot stop a method that is already running on another computer (through a webservice). The cancellation token for tasks can only stop the task from starting when the token is set. Once the task has started there is no way back for the same reason that `Thread.Abort` should (almost) never be used.

Comment: There are some cases when aborting the job is actually required. The code runs a number of third party methods to fetch data from suppliers. If the suppliers job did not respond within a certain period it would stop the whole process, therefore needs to be monitored and killed off if necessary.

Comment: Cancellation is always cooperative. The only allowed "hard kill" is to terminate an entire process. That is safe. In all other cases you *need* to establish a cooperative cancellation mechanism. Does that make sense?

Comment: I agree, but since I can't influence the suppliers code, I can only act upon my own. Therefore if I have no method of killing the suppliers job built into their webservice, the only way would surely to kill the job in its entirety.

Comment: Just to be clear: all work happens on a remote server you do not control, and you want that code to stop? Not possible without support from the "supplier". You can't kill processes on a remote server (without permissions, which you will not be granted).

Comment: No, I don't want to stop the suppliers code, but I want to abandon this lookup and move on to the next supplier

Comment: That you can do yourself if that happens in your code (which you have not yet made a statement about). Not sure what else to say. If you control the code, you can make it happen.

Comment: So I guess the question is how to terminate a task that has a single method call to a long running process?

Comment: You can't, sorry. You can only signal the method that it should terminate itself. Or move the invocation to a new child process that you can kill. Do not use Thread.Abort. I'm still unclear what code executes locally and what executes on a remote server. You cannot control a remote server at all except invoking webservices.

Comment: The jobs that run remotely are the remit of our suppliers. There may be 20 of these jobs which I will make a call to from my code, typically webservices ot httppost. My code needs to queue and run requests sequentially. As soon as a supplier responds with an 'accept', the process terminates naturally - any other response, move to next. At the front end is a user waiting for a response, so the whole process has a limit of about 60 - 90 seconds to run. If a supplier does not provide a reply for 30 seconds, it would have a knock on effect to the whole of the queue, so these need to be managed.

Comment: Of course, I could always choose to simply abandon the child thread, move on to the next, and let it finish naturally, but this seems like a more dangerous option.

Comment: When you send a webservice call, an XML document is sent over HTTP over TCP. Once that request is on the network, you can't call it back. The call will complete no matter what. You can abandon the result, or close the connection. But the remote server *will* execute the call and try to send its response. I recommend that you let the call complete, but discard its result by checking the cancellationtoken after the call. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm using task.Wait(timeout), by default my calling method will continue processing to the next supplier and the result will be ignored anyway.